# Laravel - how to make Service Class flexible?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I like to write the heavy logic in the Service class `app(MailService::class);`, however from Service class - how would you response back to Job Class to execute `$this->release()` or attempt check like `$this->attempts()`?

Similar, how would you response back for Command (`SendReminderCommand`) to pass into `$this->error()` or `$this->info()` - This should also be flexible for Controller.

I want to use Service Class to be flexible so it can be used with Job Class, Command or even Controller.

For example:

**Job Class**

```
   class SendReminderEmail extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
    {
        use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

        public function handle()
        {
            $mail = app(MailService::class);  //service class

            $this->release(10)
            $this->attempts()
        }
    }
```

**Command Class**

```
class SendReminderCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'email:reminder';
    protected $description = 'Send Reminder';

    public function handle()
    {
        $mail = app(MailService::class); //service class

        $this->info("Emails Sent");
        $this->error('Something went wrong!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `MailService` performing something other than initialization in its constructor?

Comment: @nCrazed MailService is just an example class name... can be anything   `class MailService { }` Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I was more concerned by the fact that you're not attempting to call any methods on the `MailService` instances after instantiating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your service methods so that non-query methods can be assumed to have been successful if no exception was thrown like so:

```php
public function handle(MailService $mail)
{
    try {
        $mail->performAction();
        $this->info('Action Complete');
    } catch (RecoverableProblem $e) {
        /* Recover and perhaps retry at a later time? */
    } catch (UnrecoverableProblem $e) {
        $this->error('Something went wrong!');
        /* Abort? */
    }
}
```

If you need to pass some additional information to the logging methods, simply return that information from the service methods and use the return value to build the message.

Comment: Thanks for answer. `use the return value to build the message` I am not sure what you mean. you mean return something like this `return ['success' => true, 'message' => 'information message here'];`If not you could update your answer what do you mean by that.

Comment: That depends on what is considered a failure. In most cases it's better to throw an exception on failure and let the caller (in this case your command or queue job class) handle it as it sees fit. That way there is no need for explicit success confirmation. The success is implied by the absence of exceptions and only the actual data needs to be returned by the method.

Comment: That is what I meant, how the actual data should look returned by the method?

Comment: That depends entirely on the method. There is no general answer for this.
But in case of your earlier example, instead of returning an array with success state and the message, you simply return the message string.